# How change background items selected on list view on windows store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

background items when hover any items and clear all background,symbol(v) on the right of top of the list view when selected... and if you do not mind that i want ask about how price to pay for Microsoft dev(upload application onto store) every year?????
Who do know code to change it on App.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list view item style, remove the border for the check mark.

```
<Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Margin="4">
                                <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Opacity="0" Height="40" Width="40">
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z"  Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
```

Then in the visual state transitions remove the storyboards referencing the removed elements.

```
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
```

...etc

Comment: I want red background when hower. i don't know color symbol.

Comment: please post another question